# XAML (WP8.1) scrollable ListView and fixed Grid bottom of DataTemplate

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

```xml
<DataTemplate>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid>
            ... same rows and controls 20% of screen
        </Grid>
        <ListView>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DataTemplate>
```

With this template there are

1. fixed Grid first
2. scrollable ListView second

How create template with

1. scrollable ListView at top
2. fixed Grid at bottom

?

P.S. There are online or compiled demo different xaml layout/templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put a `ListView` inside a `ScrollViewer` because you will lose virtualization if you are using it, which will degrade performance significantly.

If you want the `Grid` to always be visible then use the following:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Height="100"/> <!-- Set any fixed height -->
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

If you want the `Grid` to scroll with the list use a `Footer`:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ListView>
        <ListView.Footer>
            <!-- Set any fixed height -->
            <Grid Height="100"/>
        </ListView.Footer>
    </ListView>
</DataTemplate>
```